# What is the correct Permission to give GCP Cloud Function (CF) so that it's callable ONLY from another CF?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-iam

I need one cloud function (CF) to invoke another CF that is protected. Protected meaning it can only be invoked by other CFs but not from Internet.

Protected CF:
I disabled the "Allow unauthenticated invocations" when creating this.
I now need to give this function the correct Role and Permission so that it can be accessed from other CFs.

I have tried almost all options but keep getting 403 from the invoker.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Give this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function) a read, specifically the section of authenticating `Function-to-Function`. It should give you the insights you need to solve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify that a receiving function accepts requests from other functions by granting the Cloud Functions Invoker role to the calling function identity. More info on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function).

Cloud Functions run under a specific identity, given by the service account they run under. By default, this service account is the same as for App Engine, `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`. So by giving the invoker role to this service account, you'll allow all your other functions to call this function. You may want to give a different identity/service account to each of your functions to specify access permissions in a more granular way. More info on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity).

Comment: This doesn't work without OAuth ID token. Is there a way to block the call using GCP Permissions only?

Comment: Unfortunately not. By giving the "invoker" permission to a given service account, you already automatize the identity token validation on the receiving function's side. But the calling function still needs to provide that token and it isn't automatized by the platform.

Comment: One other limitation to this approach is, that you cannot alter the trigger uri. e.g adding '/contacts' path to the uri. That will throw 401 meaning that all internal routing logic has to be done by request param flags.