# download sourceUploadUrl pointed zip of google cloud function - where to set permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

In search for lost storage bucket I install gcp CLI, after calling:

`gcloud functions describe helloBigQuery --region=europe-central2`

I got the description including the:

`sourceUploadUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/uploads-150022839147.europe-central2.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/6cfd5e0e-c2e9-4970-b135-9e224b4b5bc6.zip`

I would like to download that ZIP.

So I gave an attempt to CURL with setting `-H 'Authorization: Bearer` to the value I got from running:

`gcloud auth print-access-token`

But what I get is 403:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>my.email@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details></Error>`

while `my.email@gmail.com` is set as administrator on both cloud storage buckets, and owner of related function.

how to set that permission for `my.email@gmail.com` correctly to be able to download that ZIP?

Comment: Does this [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539441/403-response-from-google-cloud-functions) help you?