# How do I use a separate .js file within a node.js Google Cloud function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a Google Cloud Function using the node.js runtime that simply returns the **result** of a function stored in an accompanying .js file.

My real function is bit more involved, so I've written a *very* rudimentary example below to illustrate what I'm after.

This is the function, producing a simple HTML "Hello World!" greeting, stored in **function.js**.

```
export function myFunction() {
  return '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>Hello World</h1><p></p></body></html>'
}
```

This is the **index.js** script, which I want to just *respond* with the result of *myfunction()* noted above.

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
import { myfunction } from '/workspace/function.js'

// Register an HTTP function with the Functions Framework that will be executed
// when you make an HTTP request to the deployed function's endpoint.
functions.http('helloGET', (req, res) => {
  res.send(myfunction());
});
```

And the accompanying **Package.json** below without "type":"module" included for illustration.

```
{
  "name": "json-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

If I try to deploy the function as shown above, the deployment fails and tells me I should update the package.json to include "type":"module".

> Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: (node:122) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type":"module" in the package.json. or us the .mjs extension.

And then if I do that I get a deployment error saying that the container isn't set up properly.

> Could not create or update Cloud Run service function-1, Container Healthcheck failed.  Revision 'function...' is not ready and cannot serve traffic.  The user-provided start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable.

I believe the issue is in how I am "requiring" (or not requiring) the **function.js** file.  From my trial-and-error testing (alternatively and concurrently trying the function with and without export prefix, using res.sendFile, trying to store the myfunction() result as a const...)I can see in Chrome developer tools that when the function does deploy it doesn't actually load the function.js file with it. You can see in the Function gui below that the file is there, but the only way I can "use" it is if I do res.sendFile (but then it just returns the text of the code, not the result of the code. [image]

In effect, I want the Google Cloud function to *behave* as if it's written like this...

```
functions.http('helloGET', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>Hello World</h1><p></p></body></html>');
});
```

I feel like the answer is staring me in the face but I can't find it.  Has anyone else done something like this before?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Also you might want to be clear how you reached the conclusion that `/workspace/function.js` is the correct way to import this file. We can't see your project or filesystem so we don't know how you're expecting this import to work.

Comment: Thanks, @DougStevenson!  The screenshot I included at the bottom of the post is the entire filesystem as I understand it.  This is direct from the Google Cloud Functions edit UI.  Re: "/workspace/function.js", I was using the recommendation to use the absolute path, so I ran __dirname and it returned "workspace" (I may have misinterpreted the result though).  I've also tried "./function.js" and "function.js" in its place with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was deleted, so posting the solution here in case it helps someone in the future.  No changes made to package.json, and the cloud run function permissions needed to be updated (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76015948/21749472).

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
const myfunction = require('./function.js')

functions.http('helloHttp', (req, res) => {
  res.send(myfunction());
});
```

**function.js**

```
module.exports = function myFunction() {
  return '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>Hello World</h1><p></p></body></html>'
}
```